# WCF REST Throw SerializationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, rest, wcf

i'm develop a Service with JSON.NET using POST Method and passing Model Class to Method. But every time i do submit on MVC, in WCF always throw SerializeException.

**Exception**

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' in System.ServiceModel.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' in System.ServiceModel.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' in System.ServiceModel.dll
```

**Register Interface**

```
[OperationContract]
            [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Register", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
            string Registration(StudentDetails sd);
```

**StudentDetails Model**

```
  [DataContract]
 [Serializable] 
   public class StudentDetails
        {
            private string Uname, Pass;

            [DataMember(Name = "Username")]
            public string Username
            {
                get { return Uname; }
                set { Uname = value; }
            }
            [DataMember(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password
            {
                get { return Pass; }
                set { Pass = value; }
            }
    }
```

**Register Class**

```
   public string Registration(StudentDetails sd)
    {
      string rs="";
      using (var connection = con.GetOpenConnection())
            {
                connection.Open();
                int rsa = connection.Execute("INSERT INTO Account.Login VALUES (@Username, @Password)", new {sd.Username, sd.Password });
                if (rsa == 0)
                {
                  rs = "Register Successfully";
                }
            }
        return rs;
     }
```

and as the client side, i'm using ASP MVC, this is the little code for passing Model to WCF REST

**Client Side**

```
public string Register(StudentDetails GR)
{
        string rs = "";
          try
           {
                string URLS = "http://localhost:8080/Service1.svc/";
                StudentDetails sd = new StudentDetails();
                sd.Username = GR.Username;
                sd.Password = GR.Password;
               string Serializer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sd);
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
                webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                var json = webClient.UploadString(URLS + "Register", "POST", Serializer);
                JObject rss = JObject.Parse(json);
                rs = rss["RegistrationResult"].ToString();
          }
         catch {}
      return rs;
}
```

The data are found when i use Breakpoint on MVC. However it's always throw Serializer Exception on WCF. Any Idea?